# Number of way to render an amount of money

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization

I made an algorithm to train my skill in dynamic programming and I would like to have feed back on it. This algorithm takes a money system (`int`) and have a certain amount of money to render.

Do you see any problems in this code?

```
public static int wayToRenderMemo(int[] array, int i, double cost, HashMap memo) {
    if(i>=array.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(cost < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(cost == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(memo.containsKey(String.valueOf(i)+":"+String.valueOf(cost))) {
        return (int) memo.get(String.valueOf(i)+":"+String.valueOf(cost));
    }
    else {
        int res = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            res += wayToRenderMemo(array, i+j, cost-array[j], memo);
        }
        memo.put(String.valueOf(i)+":"+String.valueOf(cost), res);
        return res;
    }
}

public static void main(String []args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100};

    double amountOfMoneyToRender = 20;
    System.out.println("Number of way to render "+amountOfMoneyToRender+"€ with the following system : "+Arrays.toString(array));
    HashMap memo = new HashMap();
    long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(wayToRenderMemo(array, 0, amountOfMoneyToRender, memo));
    long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double time2 = (t4-t3)/1000.0;
    System.out.println("Result found in : "+time2+"seconds");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I find it highly commendable to explicitly state the purpose of coding something, especially with practice code. 2¢: do so *in the code*.

Answer (score 1):

1. Java 1.5 was released in 2004, use generics for collections.
2. Consider making  `array` (terrible variable name BTW) and `memo` fields of object that does the computation instead of passing them as arguments every time
3. Why is `amountOfMoneyToRender` a double instead of `int` or `long`?
4. String.valueOf is unnecessary for `i + "some literal"`
5. Instead of using `containsKey` + `get` just do `get` and check for null.
6. It might be good idea to change loop into `for(int j = i; j < array.length; j++)`, it will make easier to spot bug in your code (with amountOfMoneyToRender=10, the result should be 11, not 100)